# How can I find specific nodes in an XDM document with Perl's XML::LibXML?

Tags: perl

Hi i'm trying to use XML::LibXML to find some nodes in xdm file and i need some help. this is part of xdm

```
<d:ctr name="Cpl">
    <d:var name="ModuleId" value="Cpl_TS_TxDxM3I0R0_"/>
    <d:var name="Enabled" value="TRUE"/>
    <d:var name="Generate" value="TRUE"/>
    <d:var name="Load" value="TRUE"/>
    <d:var name="Soft" value="3.0.2 B104427"/>
    <d:var name="URL" value="config\Cpl.xdm"/>
    <d:var name="Form" value="xdm"/>
    <d:var name="PreConfig" >
      <a:a name="IMPO" value="@DEF"/>
    </d:var>
    <d:var name="RecConfig" >
      <a:a name="IMPO" value="@DEF"/>
    </d:var>
  </d:ctr>
  <d:ctr name="CplShared">
    <d:var name="ModuleId" value="_TS_"/>
    <d:var name="Enabled" value="TRUE"/>
    <d:var name="Generate" value="TRUE"/>
    <d:var name="Load" value="TRUE"/>
    <d:var name="Soft" value="3.0.2 B104427"/>
    <d:var name="URL" 
           value="..\..\Common\config\CplShared.xdm"/>
    <d:var name="Form" value="xdm"/>
    <d:var name="PreConfig" >
      <a:a name="IMPO" value="@DEF"/>
    </d:var>
    <d:var name="RecConfig" >
      <a:a name="IMPO" value="@DEF"/>
    </d:var>
```

and i want to extract value from moduleId node.
findnodes seems to not work

```
foreach my $nodeArPackage ($xml_file->findnodes('//d:var'))
    {
        my $nameNodeFramePackage = $nodeArPackage->findnodes(name="ModuleId");

        print $nameNodeFramePackage;
    }
```

Comment: Prehaps add the code that seems to not work so other Perl devs can point out why.

Comment: Valid XML helps too.

Comment: I'm no perl dev but a quick google retuned this https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=perl%20findnodes%20example `argument to findnodes is called an XPath expression`

Comment: Yes, yes it is. And the `xpath` for an attribute isn't like that. I refer to: http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/quick_ref.html for syntax basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
my $nameNodeFramePackage = $nodeArPackage->findnodes(name="ModuleId");
```

That's not valid - if you'd run your code under `strict` and `warnings` it'll error. (You should probably do this anyway - it's very good practice).

`Bareword "name" not allowed at line ...`

And even if it wasn't, it's still not valid as an `xpath` expression. Take a look at [XML::Twig quick reference](http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/quick_ref.html) - there's a section on `xpath` expressions.

What you probably want is:

```
my $nameNodeFramePackage = $nodeArPackage->findnodes('[@name="ModuleId"]');
```

There's not really any reason you couldn't combine the two though:

```
foreach my $nameNodeFramePackage ($xml_file->findnodes('//d:var[@name="ModuleId"]')) {
    print $nameNodeFramePackage;
}
```

(NB: `XML::LibXML` doesn't install on my Windows box, so I haven't tested that xpath using it. It does work with `XML::Twig` which uses similar syntax)

Comment: You're running on Windows although your profile says you have a background in Unix? That must hurt. ;)

Comment: Yeah, somewhat frustrating. I do get to mostly write perl on Unix, it's just not in a way I can conveniently test and transfer to Stack Overflow. So I make do with Activeperl.

Comment: I used to use a virtual machine for that. Now I'm happy on my physical Ubuntu with Windows in a VM.

Comment: Oh Thanks and how can i extract value from this ?? I'm new to this